# Comparing 2 parameters in Jenkins pipeline in a single command

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

what is wrong with below code, comparing 2 strings in groovy

I am trying do the comparison between the 2 parameters in a single line to make it look tidier

```
if (params.dirname == ((params.path =~ ~/${params.dirname}/).with { matches() ? it[0] : null })) {
    print success 
}
```

Throwing Exception -

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'matches' found among steps
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Update your question to meet the standard of [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `=~ ~` - is wrong. probably should be `=~`. and everything else is also strange. not clear what values in `params.dirname` and `params.path`. to compare values maybe you just need `params.dirname == params.path` ?

Comment: params.dirname = hde, params.path = /usr/tmp/jenkins/hde/filename.txt or /usr/hde/jenkins/ing/filename.txt or any random path which has hde in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to over-complicate your use case. According to:

> params.dirname = hde, params.path = /usr/tmp/jenkins/hde/filename.txt or /usr/hde/jenkins/ing/filename.txt or any random path which has hde in it

you are trying to find if given string `a` contains substring `b`. It can be done using Java's method `String.contains(String substring)`. Alternatively you can use regular expression for that, but `String.contains()` just looks a few times simpler to understand what is your intention. Consider following Groovy script:

```
def params = [
        dirname: 'hde',
        path: '/usr/tmp/jenkins/hde/filename.txt'
]

// Using String.contains()
if (params.path.contains(params.dirname)) {
    println "Path '${params.path}' contains '${params.dirname}'"
}

// Using regular expression
if (params.path ==~ /(.*)${params.dirname}(.*)/) {
    println "Path '${params.path}' contains '${params.dirname}'"
}
```

When you run it both `if` statements evaluates to `true`:

```
Path '/usr/tmp/jenkins/hde/filename.txt' contains 'hde'
Path '/usr/tmp/jenkins/hde/filename.txt' contains 'hde'
```